# Tried to synchronously call anonymous function from a different thread. with DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just upgraded to react native 0.67.3 and now when I open my app, which uses react navigation v6, I receive this error:

```
Occurred in worklet location: /Users/path/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/reanimated2/hook/useAnimatedStyle.js (332:24)

Possible solutions are:
a) If you want to synchronously execute this method, mark it as a Worklet
b) If you want to execute this method on the JS thread, wrap it using runOnJS
2022-03-09 10:54:14.180294-0500 project[1949:15686] [native] Tried to synchronously call anonymous function from a different thread.

Occurred in worklet location: /Users/path/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/reanimated2/hook/useAnimatedStyle.js (332:24)
```

I'm currently using DrawerNavigator like this:

```
         <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" >
            <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Here are my versions of the relevant packages:

```
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.11",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0"
```

Any ideas what in DrawerNavigator may be causing this and how to fix?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

React Navigation Drawer Navigator  V6 is using `react-native-reanimated`V2 which employ special worklet function to synchronously run code for both JavaScript and UI thread.

Try to fallback to old `react-native-reanimated` V1 by set `useLegacyImplementation`  to `true`

```js
 <Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation={true} initialRouteName="Home" >
     <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
 </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Comment: That worked immediately, thank you very much!

Comment: no offense but how's that even a solution, that's just an ugly workaround

Comment: I agree with you. This was a temporary solution and I think it will be outdated as new React Navigation Drawer release

Comment: it works, but it's a temporary fix

Comment: Still works to this day!

Answer (score -3):

O react-native-reanimatedV2 implementa a função de **'worklet'** que é especifica para executar código de uma maneira síncrona em thread JavaScript/UI. Portanto deves usar: `'worklet';` logo no inicio da sua função, dessa forma.

`

```
function DrawerNav() {
  'worklet';
   return (
     <Drawer.Navigator useLegacyImplementation={true} initialRouteName="Home" >
       <Drawer.Screen name="HomeStack" component={HomeStack} />
   </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}
```

`

Comment: in english please

Comment: Would love to see where the docs mention this. I get a syntax error when placing `worklet` in my navigator. It does work, however, when using the legacy implementation, but it’s not at all ideal.